# how to make function for set visibility of All images in custom listview in adapter?

Tags: android, image, listview, hide, show

how to make function for set visibility of All images in custom listview in adapter , when i click button hide_All_image or button show_all_image?

here my adapter...

```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_list_item, null);

    final TextView judul = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.judul);
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.gambar_tulisan);

    HashMap<String, String> tulisan = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tulisan = data.get(position);


    String varjudul=tulisan.get(FavoriteActivity.TAG_JUDUL);
    judul.setText(Html.fromHtml(varjudul));

    String gambar_string = tulisan.get(ContentActivity.TAG_GAMBAR);


        if (gambar_string.equals("")) {
            thumb_image.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        } else {
            thumb_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(tulisan.get(ContentActivity.TAG_GAMBAR_PATH), thumb_image); 
        }   
        return vi ;

        }

public Set_Visibility_Gone(){

    // how the code to setvisibility GONE All thumb_image  ?

}


public Set_Visibility_Visible(){

    // how the code to setvisibility Visible All thumb_image  ?

}
```

**before i click hide all  image**

[image: before hide image]

**after i clikc hide all image**

[image: after hide]

thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: where is your imageview.??

Comment: ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.gambar_tulisan);

image in listview...

Comment: so, you want to hide or show thumb_image .?

Comment: i just edited my ask,  can you see the image ?

Comment: so, what is your main problem ?

Comment: i don't know how code to hide all image, and to show all code image, if i click that both button.., can you help me ? :(

Comment: show my below answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a visibility flag in your adapter.

```
boolean isVisible;
```

Toggle the flag in your methods:

For example:

```
public Set_Visibility_Visible(){
    this.isVisible = true;
}
```

And in your getView method:

```
if (gambar_string.equals("")|| !isVisible) {
    thumb_image.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
} else {
    thumb_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(tulisan.get(ContentActivity.TAG_GAMBAR_PATH), thumb_image); 
}
```

Remember to call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged() right after you call those methods to change visibility of your images.

Comment: how implemnt inner this code sir ?
`
public Set_Visibility_Gone(){

    // how the code to setvisibility GONE All thumb_image  ?

}


public Set_Visibility_Visible(){

    // how the code to setvisibility Visible All thumb_image  ?

}`

Answer (score 0):

on Show image button onclick listener:

```
thumb_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

on Hide image button onclick listener:

```
thumb_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```